# How to create each page as PDF from existing PDF using mPDF in Laravel

Tags: pdf, laravel-5.5, mpdf

```
use ZanySoft\LaravelPDF\PDF;

$mpdf = new PDF();
$mpdf->SetImportUse();

$pagecount = $mpdf->SetSourceFile(storage_path() . '/app/public/applications/test.pdf');

// test.pdf have 2 pages $pagecount have value 2.

for($i=1; $i <= $pagecount ; $i++) {
   $tplId = $mpdf->ImportPage($i);          
   $mpdf->addPage();
   $mpdf->UseTemplate($tplId);
   // store each page as pdf file
   $new_file_name = "new-".$i.".pdf";
   $mpdf->Output($new_file_name, \Mpdf\Output\Destination::FILE);
}
```

I am getting an error **Class 'Mpdf\Output\Destination' not found**. I have tried below things as second argument of Output();

1. $mpdf->Output($new_file_name, \PDF\Output\Destination::FILE);
2. $mpdf->Output($new_file_name, \Mpdf\Mpdf\Output\Destination::FILE);

But, it is not working. Please help to store fetch page store as PDF file direct on directory.

Answer (score 1):

`ZanySoft\LaravelPDF\PDF` uses mPDF in version `6.1` which does not have output destination class constants yet.

Use a plain string:

```
$mpdf->Output($new_file_name, 'F');
```

Or use composer package `mpdf/mpdf` in version `>=7` directly.